# Installing libxmlsec1 on windows

Tags: python, saml, libxml2, onelogin, xml-libxml

I am trying to provide SSO via OneLogin in my Flask/Python (2.7) app on windows.
I am trying to use sample app provided by OneLogin and currently going through installation of required packages.  I hit a dead end with libxmlsec1.  While I was trying to install **dm.xmlsec.binding**, I came across this requirement

> In addition, you must have installed the development packages for libxml2 and the XML security library (often called libxmlsec1) on the operating system level.

I was trying to find out the way to install the **libxmlxec1** on Windows and landed on this page http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html and ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/, but I just cannot figure out how to install these binaries to "**install the development package**".

Can someone please shed light on this confusion?

How should I install this thing?

Answer (score 0):

you can edit the Python package where 'xmlsec.exe' is required and set the exact physical address of the file.
in my case it was editing 'C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\saml2\sigver.py'